# How do I put web applications in my Unity Launcher?

Tags: 10.10, unity, google-chrome

Early screenshots of Unity showed web applications on the launcher that would get launched in the browser.

[image]

I heavily use Chrome's "appmode", which makes .desktop files of web applications and runs them as a seperate application. I would like to put these applications on my launcher so that when I click on it it launches gmail in a separate window, like a separate application from my browser.

Am I missing something? Launching the application from the .desktop file from the file manager just opens it my existing browser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ken's answer complicates the subject a bit, I think.
Unity has a switch, -b, I think, that allows that. like `unity -b http://mail.google.com`

I'm not sure if it's really `-b`, so you better check with `unity --help`.

Comment: Note: This doesn't use app mode, but considering the other solution this is a "good enough" work around.

Comment: It appears the `-b` flag is missing in 11.04

Answer (score 8):

Only way I know right now is with gconf.  Here is an example, replace the name and path of the desktop file with your's.  In my case it is /home/ken/.local/share/applications/chrome-http___mail.google.com_a_vandine.org.desktop

```
gconftool --type string --set /desktop/unity/launcher/favorites/app-chrome-http___mail.google.com_a_vandine.org.desktop/desktop_file /home/ken/.local/share/applications/chrome-http___mail.google.com_a_vandine.org.desktop 


gconftool --type list --list-type=string --set /desktop/unity/launcher/favorites/favorites_list $(gconftool --get /desktop/unity/launcher/favorites/favorites_list| sed "s/]//g"),app-chrome-http___mail.google.com_a_vandine.org.desktop]
```

Comment: Thanks! Now off to file a bug about how convoluted that is and the window matching being weird.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the latest build of Chromium (>11.0.696.57) this now works with Unity. Create the app shorcut from within Chromium then drag it on to the Unity bar. Not sure how long it will be before this makes it in to Chrome.

Comment: Are you on 11.04? If so can you update this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/31427/how-do-i-put-a-web-application-on-the-launcher

Comment: Yes I'm on 11.04. I have posted.

Comment: this is now broken again with Chrome 14.