# How do I add a static quicklist for Opera to open new tabs and windows?

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher, opera, quicklists

How can I add more options to Opera's quicklist such as: new tab, new private tab, new window, mail, etc?

Answer (score 2):

Basically the same way as shown in this question: [How do I add a static quicklist that opens a web page?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32991/how-do-i-add-a-static-quicklist-that-opens-a-web-page)

Just change the `Exec=` lines for the quicklist items (running `opera --help` in a terminal will get you the commands you can use).

Here's how the desktop file (`/usr/share/applications/opera-browser.desktop`) would look like when adding a private tab quicklist item:

```
...
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=PrivateTab

[PrivateTab Shortcut Group]
Name=Open a new private tab
Exec=opera -newprivatetab
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Answer (score 2):

**How-to**:

1) Open a terminal and enter the following:

- `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/opera-browser.desktop`

2) At the bottom of the file, add the following lines:

```
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewTab;NewPrivateTab;NewWindow;Mail;

[NewTab Shortcut Group]
Name=New Tab
Exec=opera -newtab
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[NewPrivateTab Shortcut Group]
Name=New Private Tab
Exec=opera -newprivatetab
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=New Window
Exec=opera -newwindow
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Mail Shortcut Group]
Name=Mail
Exec=opera -mail
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

3) Save and close Gedit.

4) Add the icon to your launcher if it is not already and your quicklists should now be working.

[image]

**Tips**:

You can also make Mail open a new tab at a specific address if you want by replacing its Exec command to be (for example):

```
Exec=opera -newtab "http://www.gmail.com/"
```

**Source**:

http://kyleabaker.com/2011/04/02/quicklists-for-opera-in-unity/