# Chrome App Icon is in low-resolution during the application switch

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 and using Google Chrome (not Chromium).
I just want to use the "app" feature in chrome and I created application shortcuts for Gmail, Google Calendar, and things like that. But the problem is during application switch (ALT + TAB). In that, Chrome's icon is the app icon. For example, when I launch Gmail as a chrome app, the icon is the gmail icon. But that icon is in low-resolution so it kinda makes the view ugly. What I want is I just want to change that icon, but don't know how to do it.

Sorry for my poor English.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome uses a site's favicon for it's application icon. Many of these are low resolution. In this question I link to some resources where you can find higher resolution icons:

- [How do I put a web application on the Launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31427/how-do-i-put-a-web-application-on-the-launcher)

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings -> Main Menu
Then find your application, perhaps under "Internet" folder, then click properties for that app, and click on the icon, you can then select a different one-

Answer (score 0):

Look in these areas for better hi-res icons to exchange with the questionable one

Where are Icons and Themes store

/usr/share/themes

/usr/share/icons

/usr/share/pixmaps

as well as some user-specific directories for the user-created themes:

~/.themes

~/.icons

~/pixmaps are generally used for menu icons.
~/share/icons are generally used for theme icons.\