# How can I make Chromium app windows count as "their own application" in the Unity launcher?

Tags: 11.04, launcher, chromium, window, application-development

I'm trying to add a Chromium app window (chromium-browser --app=http://example.org) to the launcher. I've put together a .desktop file and it works, but all instances of Chromium get lumped together. If I've got a normal browser window already running, the app will be listed with Chromium. If I start the appwindow first, normal chromium windows will be listed with it. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Making a new Chromium profile for the app works around the problem (this is specific to 11.04, 11.10 fixes this issue at the Unity-level.):

> To open a website as an app window, add `--app=http://example.org` to the launcher parameters for chromium. Making and using a new profile is as easy as adding `--user-data-dir=/path/to/profile`

As long as you put a different path to each web application they will be treated as separate applications.

- [Reference](http://blag.alexandos.org/2011/08/web-app-indows-and-the-launcher/) blog post
- [How do I put a web application on the Launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31427/how-do-i-put-a-web-application-on-the-launcher)

Comment: this fix is still required in 11.10 with Chrome 14.0.835.202-r103287