# opening web locations in Unity

Tags: 11.04, unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I put a web application on the Launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31427/how-do-i-put-a-web-application-on-the-launcher)

Using 11.04 at the moment - 11.10 crashed!!!!, I have  been using the Gnome environment but have decided to try UNITY!
In the Gnome environment I set up icons on the top of screen launcher bar (right click et al) and found these very useful to access most of my regular web accounts - eg hotmail, ebay and other sites. I have no idea how to do this in the Unity environment?

I have searched the web for internet launchers in unity and just don't see any real reference on how to do this - applications yes - locations no! Has anyone got an idea of how to do this? Please respond in simple terms for a complete novice!

Thank you