# How to get new blue Tweetdeck on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

As you guys know, new desktop Tweetdeck is out for Windows and Mac.

I am using Tweetdeck on Air in my Ubuntu. On their website, Air based version is not available.

Can I get that blue iconed Tweetdeck on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5):

Adobe AIR for linux is [no longer supported](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2011/06/adobe-air-and-linux-increasing-distribution-on-devices.html). However Tweetdeck has an awesome web client that I use:

[image]

It's in the [Chrome store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/tweetdeck) or you can just go to tweetdeck.com in Firefox.

Comment: Jorge, I knew this. But I want the native app. Chrome closed. Tweetdeck closed. Not a good thing for me. :)

Comment: Are you aware of any good tweetdeck alternative for Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 3):

Just install [wine [image: Install wine]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wine). It's available in the Software Center. Or run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Then you can just go to [www.tweetdeck.com](http://www.tweetdeck.com/) and click on the download button. That will install it under Wine.

I'm using 12.04, and I have Wine installed, and actually just installed tweetdeck before I posted this, so I can verify it does in fact work.

Answer (score 3):

I know my answer is very similar to the other ones, but I was facing same issue one week ago, and I wanna share the experience to finally being 'able' (or mostly) to use TweetDeck as Linux app.

I tried Polly, then Birdie, but nah, I was missing TweetDeck because of the look and feel and the way better column management that TD has compared to Polly. So I started using it from the browser in Chrome, as the [Chrome-App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tweetdeck-by-twitter/hbdpomandigafcibbmofojjchbcdagbl).

Then it ocurred to me that may be I was able to create a link from Ubuntu Apps directly to the Chrome-App, just as you do it from your Android/iOS/FirefoxOS phones. I looked all over and I found [the way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31427/how-do-i-put-a-web-application-on-the-launcher) to do it.

So summing up, all you gotta do is:

- Open Google Chrome / Chromium (whichever one is fine)
- Go to the TweetDeck WebApp
- Go to Menu > Tools > Create Application Shortcut... (When into the TD App)

[image: menu in chrome]

*(from now on the next ones are optional)*

- Accept creating the icon in Desktop

[image: desktop]

- Search for a nice image to use it as Logo and download it in the Desktop (because the other one is
  like 10x10px (I used [this one](http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/ad/e6/ff/ade6ff77-dec7-cdf5-3712-7a8fcdcbc0e2/app.png))
- Right click the "WebApp" in Desktop, go to "Properties" and drag the
  icon image in top of the one in the Properties Window

[image]

- Open the "WebApp"
- Lock it to Launcher

[image]

- Enjoy

Well, now I'm pretty happy again with a great Twitter Linux "Client", It works exactly same way as it used to work in Windows.