# How do I use Ubuntu's web application integration?

Tags: webapps

I've read that Ubuntu [will support web applications](http://blog.canonical.com/2012/07/19/introducing-ubuntu-web-apps-setting-the-web-free-of-the-browser/) out of the box, how can I set this up on my computer to play with it?

Comment: This was posted 5 years ago.  You really think just posting a link is an adequate way to make a question?  Here we are in July 2017 and my search brought up your question.  But I find it is useless.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

#### Installation

The webapps integration is included in Ubuntu 12.10 and newer. When you visit sites in Firefox or Chromium that have the integration enabled you will be prompted to add the site as an application, here's a list of sites that have support:

- https://launchpad.net/webapps

For fully integrated sites like google docs, you should see things like Dash integration:

[image]

After the site has been added you can launch it from the dash, or add it to your launcher, just like other applications.

The project homepage (where you can file bug reports) is here: https://launchpad.net/webapps

#### Developer Information

- [Developer Getting Started](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.04/javascript/index.html) - if you want to integrate directly from your web application.
- [Developer Tutorial](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/app-developer-cookbook/unity/integrating-tumblr-to-your-desktop/) - if you want to write a userscript to support a web application.
- [API Documentation](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/devel/ubuntu-13.10/javascript/web-docs/)

#### To Uninstall

- [How do I remove a website from Ubuntu's web applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166655/how-do-i-remove-a-website-from-ubuntus-web-applications)

More info: [https://launchpad.net/~webapps/+archive/preview](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebapps/+archive/preview)

#### Related Topics and References:

- http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/ubuntu-unveil-new-web-apps-feature-for-12-10
- http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/how-to-install-ubuntus-new-web-apps-feature
- http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/list-of-that-websites-support-unitys-new-web-apps-feature
- [How do I put a web application on the Launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31427/how-do-i-put-a-web-application-on-the-launcher)

Comment: It seems that these apps lack discoverability. Any chance that this will be incorporated into the Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: +1 for the post, but [Developer Getting Started](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.04/javascript/index.html) and [API Documentation](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.04/javascript/unity-web-api-reference.html) generate 404 error - Not Found.

Comment: The dev links for webapps seemed to have moved to here as a new launching off point: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/web/

Comment: Gads, what a linkfest.  And here we are 5 year later - is any of this relevant?  How long would it take to go through them and find out?  This isn't an answer.  It is now July 2017 and Ubuntu is at 16.04 LTS.    Maybe time to retire this whole thread.  Either that, or actually give a real answer, please.