# How do I get the browser to reask me to integrate with a website?

Tags: webapps

I'm using [webapp integration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165662/how-do-i-install-and-use-ubuntus-web-application-integration) and I accidentally clicked "No" when asked if I want to integrate with the website.

How can I have Firefox or Chrome reask me to integrate the site with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is currently no UI for this but there is a workaround. First install [dconf-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools] and then run `dconf-editor`

Then navigate to `com.canonical.unity.webapps`

[image]

And adjust the domains allowed. To reset them all you can do this command:

```
gsettings reset com.canonical.unity.webapps allowed-domains
```

Or you can also press the 'Set to Default' button

Comment: This answer is if you accidentally clicked "Yes", I guess. If you accidentally clicked "No", just remove from "dontask-domains", or use the Firefox UI as explained by Bruno Pereira.

Comment: This is no longer the best answer. There is a UI in Firefox now.

Answer (score 14):

Chromium now gives the user the opportunity to have a finer amount of control over the revocation of previous decisions such as the one showed above.

(Using the latest chromium provided in the package)

Go to "chrome://settings", then open the advanced settings section where there should be a "Desktop Integration" section with a checked checkbox ("Allow integration"), and a button. Click on the button and the websites for which you previously made a decision are listed. 
Removing any site from the list will re-trigger the integration step,

See:

[image: Desktop integration settings in Chromium]

Comment: Note that Firefox offers the same functionality through the "General" section (at the bottom of it) of the preferences panel,

Comment: +1.. Pictures and screenshots would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Image of desktop integration added

Comment: It works for me on Chromium, but not on Firefox. The list of sites appears empty there. Looking at dconf editor (com.canonical.unity.webapps) , `allowed-domains` contains a list of the site s I've already made a decision for and `dontask-domains` is empty there.

Comment: Help! I don't have this "Desktop Integration" section. I have the webapps extension installed and enabled

Comment: In Chromium `Desktop Integration` is changed to `Installed Websites`

Answer (score 13):

1. On Firefox, go to **Edit** > **Preferences** > **General** tab.
2. There you'll see a **Desktop integration** header. Click on the **Exceptions...** button
   [image: Preferences]
3. Use the **-** button to remove all the website entries you'd like to be re-prompted to integrate with.
4. Click **Close**

That's it :)

Comment: Not there in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @saji89 Webapps were only a technical preview on Ubuntu 12.04 and are not fully supported there. For full webapps support, Ubuntu 12.10 is required.

Comment: What if it's not there and you're on 14.04?

Answer (score 4):

Edit > Preferences > General.

Make sure that the *Prompt integration options from any website* is checked and click on the **Exceptions** button. From the websites list there choose the website you want to integrate and press the <kbd>-</kbd> button and close the dialog box and the preferences window

[image]

Reload the web page or visit the site again and you should be asked if you want to integrate the website features on your desktop again.

Comment: There is no such option longer availabe in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: how do you launch or start `unity-webapps-gmail`?

Answer (score 4):

**How to re-prompt promp for webapp to launch, unity-webapp-gmail run reinstall (tags for search engines :**

In chrome -> `chrome://chrome/settings/` -> advanced settings(check) -> installed websites -> Notify me when the website I am visiting can run as an application.

[image: settings]

OR

If you've already disabled the app try looking at exceptions.
Later on you may want to click the icon which is located in URL bar left to bookmark star icon.

[image: URL bar]

Comment: the second part of the answer is exactly what i was looking for, thank you! most of the other answers are outdated or simply don't work in chrome (v28)