# How to manage "Unity WebApps Chromium extension" different options?

Tags: chromium, webapps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the browser to reask me to integrate with a website?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165688/how-do-i-get-the-browser-to-reask-me-to-integrate-with-a-website)

I have installed the **WebApps** preview from the dedicated PPA, and more or less things are working for a site (google reader) that I have accepted to install. I'm using only google Chromium and Firefox is not installed.
My question is **how can I manage the other options?** I mean, when a site is compatible, a **banner** with this phrase is displayed:

> For easier access to GMail and extra features, you can install it as a
>   separate application that doesn't need a web browser. Would you like
>   to install it now? [Never for this site] [Yes]

I have three options: press the button "***Never for this site***" or the button "***Yes***", or renounce  and simply close the banner.

1. If I choose "**Yes**" I see that the webapp is installed. OK
2. If I choose "**Never for this site**", and after I changed my mind, how can I "restore" the banner?
3. If I choose "**Yes**", and after I changed my mind, how can I completely uninstall the webapp, and "restore" the banner?