# How to change trust settings in unity-webapps

Tags: webapps

I installed unity-webapps and I allowed GMail to integrate, however disallowed access to Google Docs and something else. Now I want to review and change the settings. How to do that?

I found how to remove single integrations, but I never get the configuration dialog back where I confirmed, what to allow and what not.

Answer (score 1):

The integration settings dialog (e.g. described in [How to manage "Unity WebApps Chromium extension" different options?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169282/how-to-manage-unity-webapps-chromium-extension-different-options)) actually shows both applications for which you declined and allowed integration. It basically allows to you to retrigger an integration.

If you remove a given Web App from this list, you don't see the integration prompt again as you navigate the website?