# How do I remove a site's desktop integration done via Ubuntu webapps?

Tags: webapps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove a website from Ubuntu’s web applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166655/how-do-i-remove-a-website-from-ubuntus-web-applications)

I have recently integrated launchpad site, to my desktop using the Ubuntu desktop apps feature(I just accepted the integration) when I loaded Launchpad in Firefox.
I would like to remove the desktop integration, how can I do that? I couldn't find any option for the same.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/169282/how-to-manage-unity-webapps-chromium-extension-different-options/173004#173004 or the linked answers for the Firefox equivalent,

Comment: Hi @AlexAbreu, Both the answers in the link you said don;t work for me. While one is for chromium(which is not my case), the other option is no longer seen in Firefox.

Comment: @saji89, You should update your question to reflect this then since that may not be apparent to the people who think that this is a duplicate.

Comment: @saji89 Is the scope of this really different from the scope [there](http://askubuntu.com/questions/166655/how-do-i-remove-a-website-from-ubuntus-web-applications)? If not, you might consider instead commenting there to point out the limitations of the existing answers, and perhaps adding a bounty (you can explain your needs in the bounty description). Right now it's unclear how this question is *different* from that; if the answers there are insufficient but the question is the same, the solution is to have more or better answers there, not to have another identical question open.