# How do I reenable webapps prompts in 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, webapps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the browser to reask me to integrate with a website?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165688/how-do-i-get-the-browser-to-reask-me-to-integrate-with-a-website)

I hit the 'Don't show me again' button on the webapps integration prompt. How do I reenable them or how can I alternatively add webapps to the dash?