# How do I re-enable desktop integration with websites?

Tags: webapps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the browser to reask me to integrate with a website?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165688/how-do-i-get-the-browser-to-reask-me-to-integrate-with-a-website)

The first time Facebook came up after clean install of 12.10 I wasn't signed in so I declined Webapps query to install for that site. Ok, now after I have facebook setup how do I get webapps to ask again for Facebook?