# How to install a web app after dismissing it initially?

Tags: installation, webapps

There are some web apps that I decided not to install initially; I selected "Do not ask again" for the prompt.  Now that I have changed my mind, how do I go about installing that web app for a particular browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/165688/how-do-i-get-the-browser-to-reask-me-to-integrate-with-a-website or http://askubuntu.com/questions/228211/how-do-i-enable-a-webapp-if-i-refused-to-in-the-past?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Open the software center and search for `unity-webapps`.  There you can install the ones you want.

[image]

You can also use the command: `sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-<webapp-name>`

Make sure you have the following packages installed:

```
unity-webapps-service libunity-webapps0 xul-ext-unity libufe-xidgetter0
```

You can install them with:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-service libunity-webapps0 xul-ext-unity libufe-xidgetter0
```

Comment: Thanks, I did that and when I re-open the software center it shows that it is installed.  However, when I visit the website (Google+ in this case) nothing happens.

Comment: @user82692 What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox 18.0.1
Also, I have tried signing out, and restarting the computer.

Comment: Updated answer.  Please try again.

Comment: That still didn't do the trick; I've been using Firefox for a couple of days now and the option to add webapps for neither Google+ nor Facebook popped up.

Comment: Looks like this posting has the solution I needed:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/165688/how-do-i-get-the-browser-to-reask-me-to-integrate-with-a-website