# Cannot get web-apps working in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, unity, firefox, webapps

I have been using vanilla Ubuntu 12.10 since it came out, and I will be upgrading to 13.04 in a month or two. However, I recently decided to try to install a couple of web-apps. I was unable to do so, even with some Googling.

I have enabled "Prompt integration options for any website" in my Firefox general settings and cleared any exceptions. I have checked that the 'unity-webapps-service' service is installed, and I have installed e.g. the 'unity-webapps-twitter' package, amongst others.

I have opened up dconf Editor and set to default all the settings under com>canonical>unity>webapps and I have even run the command 'gsettings reset com.canonical.unity.webapps allowed-domains'

Nothing seems to work in order to allow me to use or install Ubuntu webapps. Is there anyone who knows a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I installed chromium and `unity-chromium-extension` and there it started working (you may want to remove some exceptions too: https://askubuntu.com/a/223331/16234). I cannot get it to work with Firefox after trying. However, I tried to disable webapps some time ago so maybe I was to brutal about it.