# How do I remove a website from Ubuntu's web applications?

Tags: webapps

I thought I would try out the new webapps ppa and everything seems to be working fine. However, google reader now floods my messaging menu with all my feeds and turns the icon blue. How can I remove a specific site (google reader) from accessing webapps after I have accepted it?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

**Update**

Easy way for 12.10 onwards:

Go to the Software Center and search for the specific web app and uninstall it. E.g.

`unity-webapps-gmail` or `unity-webapps-googledocs`

---

**Hard way, for 12.04 and older Ubuntu versions**

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> , run `dconf-editor`.

Now go to com → canonical → unity → webapps.

Edit `Allowed domain value` and remove the undesired entry.

[image]

To prevent any more popups for a site, add the site URL to:

Firefox :`Edit>preferences>General> Desktop integration > exception`

or

Chrome  : `Settings > Extension > Desktop integration > Exception`

- [How do I disable unity webapps notifications from popping up everytime I visit a supported webpage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206710/how-do-i-disable-unity-webapps-notifications-from-popping-up-everytime-i-visit-a)

Comment: How is this done in Firefox 38, where I'm unable to locate: Edit>preferences>General> Desktop integration > exception ???

Answer (score 17):

*(A small addition to Web-E's excellent answer.)*

Go to the **Dash → Ubuntu Software Center → search 'unity-webapps'**

You'll now see a list of all the web apps supported by the Unity desktop. Web apps you've installed will have a tick mark on them, and from there installing/removing web apps should be goddamn easy!

---

**WARNING!** Do NOT remove the *unity-webapps-service* package (titled "Service for Web Apps integration with the Unity desktop"). This program runs the Desktop service used for Web Apps integration with Unity desktop.

---

[image: Ubuntu Software Center search results for 'unity-webapps']

Answer (score 16):

The .desktop files for these web applications are located in `~/.local/share/applications`.
Removing these files (e.g. Googleplusgooglecom.desktop, LinkedInlinkedincom.desktop) will immediately remove the entries from the messaging menu.

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12267655

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me.  This response should be marked as the answer

Answer (score 7):

There definitely needs to be an easier way, but for now, you can use dconf-editor and remove the URL from the "allowed-domains" list at com → canonical → unity → webapps.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't find the web app in the Software Center, so I just used apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-webapps-gmail
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-webapps-googledocs
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have already «removed» the webapp with *dconf-editor* or *unsettings* and it still shows on the dash, then you have to manually delete it.

1. Open the file manager
2. Click View > Show Hidden Files (alternatively CTRL + h)

[image]

3. Open this folder: **.local**
4. Open this folder: **share**
5. Open this folder: **applications**
6. Search the «desktop» file you want and delete it.

Done!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Unsettings](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings/index.html) to enable and disable installed web apps:

[image]

In the "Web apps" tab remove the undesired domains from the "Pre-authorized" (**1**) or "Enabled" (**2**) fields (that are the `allowed-domains` and `preauthorized-domains` entries in `dconf-editor`) and at them to the "Disabled" (**3**) field, if you do not want to be asked for them any more (`dontask-domains` in `dconf-editor`).

Use the "Enable Web apps" switch (**4**) to switch off the whole web apps support.

Answer (score 1):

Drag the webapp from the dash to the trash icon. Works for me.

Comment: it just close the application, doesn't uninstall it. If you reopen the site, the icon will appear again.

Answer (score 1):

quickest solution : go to browers' extensions/addons setting and disable all mentioning ubuntu - so for firefox do :  URL :  about:addons    chrome use tools -> extentions

[image]

Comment: I like this answer. It worked for me in Firefox 38 (the version where preferences began to be handle within tabs instead of popup dialog windows).

Answer (score 0):

You may do :

`sudo apt-get remove --purge unity-webapps-gmail`

or

`sudo apt-get remove --purge unity-webapps-googledocs`

--purge is important if you want a complete uninstall (for instance to remove the tray icon).

Answer (score 0):

***For Google Chrome webapps***

- Visit: chrome://apps/

[A snapshot of what you may see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQpVf.png)

- Right click on the app you want to remove
- Then select: "remove from Chrome" option