# How to remove the web app shortcut created by chromium?

Tags: chromium, shortcuts, webapps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove a website from Ubuntu's web applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166655/how-do-i-remove-a-website-from-ubuntus-web-applications)

I use Chromium's Create application Shortcut Feature and when I opted to make the shortcut, I chose to not make a Desktop Icon and have it only appear in the application menu. All fine it is there in the menu now but I want to remove it, how do I do that??

Just wanted to check the new web app integration feature but this is just a shortcut :/

Answer (score 19):

Delete `/home/user/.local/share/applications/yourapp.desktop`.

(Replace **`user`** with your username and **`yourapp`** with the name of the application.)

Comment: thank you but in users only trash zeitgeist named folders are present :(

Comment: thank you very much got it but do i have to delete any additional associated files with it???

Comment: For example, in my case, deleting "/home/phoenix/.local/share/applications/angrybirds.desktop" erase the shortcut from the dash. Is not necesary delete any aditional file. Again, sorry for my bad english :P

Comment: thanks very much it worked but later i found bleach bit also does the job..

Comment: @IndronilMondal Please mark the answer as accepted as you reported, that it works, or write your own answer (with the bleach bit thingy) and accept it. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I know this isn't for Ubuntu specifically. Of note is that I had to restart in order for them to not show up in the Unity dash. There is probably a command to run to refresh it but ya know...