# How do I completely remove web apps?

Tags: webapps

I could not get the new web apps preview to work properly on my 12.04 system, so I decided to remove it using the following code:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge 
sudo ppa-purge ppa:webapps/preview 
sudo apt-get remove gnome-control-center-signon signond signon-keyring-extension signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-ui libunity-webapps-chromium unity-chromium-extension unity-lens-gdocs unity-lens-photo unity-scope-flickr xul-ext-webaccounts xul-ext-unity xul-ext-websites-integration
```

However, this does not remove already created web apps, which are still accessible via the Unity Dash. In my case the Google Reader and Reddit web apps are still available in the Dash.

Any help completely removing these web apps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove a website from Ubuntu's web applications?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/166655/how-do-i-remove-a-website-from-ubuntus-web-applications)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install the package `alacarte` and launch it - if you browse the menus you should be able to find the web apps there as launchers, and delete them.

Comment: Whiskers75, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you! It turns out alacarte comes pre-installed and is called "Main Menu".