# How do I uninstall a unity web app?

Tags: webapps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove a website from Ubuntu’s web applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166655/how-do-i-remove-a-website-from-ubuntus-web-applications)

I accidentally installed the youtube unity web app, and now a "youtube" icon appears in my dash.  When I click on the icon, a firefox window opens to "http://www.http.com//www.youtube.com", which appears to be a generic domain squatter landing site.
I've uninstalled the "unity-webapps-youtube" package, but the icon is still there.