# Is there a GUI way to see what webapps I have installed?

Tags: webapps

I tried checking anything related to web apps in System Settings like the "Online Accounts" but I could not find anything that listed the webapps I have enabled.

Comment: please explain the main difference between this question and [my question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/291039/is-there-any-file-manager-that-highlights-names-that-are-searched-for/291052#291052) which makes one eligible for closing?! the difference between "Is there a gui" and "Is there a file manager"!

Comment: @CutieKrait - At the time of this question, webapps had several features that kept adding up. The question at the time was relevant for a problem users had when they started accumulating several webapps (Which appeared in the launcher). For your question, it is more of a feature request for a file manager (Which made it off-topic) but I see you accepted an answer that involved a terminal way. Since this is acceptable, it simply means you are not just looking for a file manager but any way of doing the highlight. In any case, My question is a dupe yours is not off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a dedicated GUI, but as a workaround, you can use `dconf-editor` to see the websites you've enabled webapps for.

This is described in more detail in a [previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166655/how-do-i-remove-a-website-from-ubuntus-web-applications).

Answer (score 1):

They are normal packages, simply search for unity-webapps in Software Center (or Synaptics).
Note that they might appear as "hidden technical items" in the bottom in software Center.