# What does "Would you like to install Twitter" mean?

Tags: firefox, webapps

Firefox in Ubuntu 12.10 pops up messages such as (similar messages for Reddit, Facebook, etc.):

"Would you like to install Twitter for extra features and quicker access?"

[image]

What do they mean? What exactly gets installed and where?

Comment: Thomas Sisson (23 Oct 2012 at 13:29 UTC) asks for clarification:

What does this mean if you use Kubuntu, Xubuntu, or other desktops or window managers and don't use Unity? Can I still access the installed web apps?

Comment: After reading the OP and the answer I was wondering about the possible advantages of using it. Well, [the documentation](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/webapps/) can give us some good reasons to install web apps.

Comment: To uninstall it review this post: [How do I remove twitter and/or other things I “install” in FireFox](http://askubuntu.com/q/166655/62483)

Comment: In order to make this decision we need to know what the pros and cons are of installing or refusing to install. The link to the documentation given above goes to a page that does not exist any more.

Comment: +1 @GailGardner ... here's an updated version of that same "developer" link: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/web/ (which may be too technical for the average user). That webapp popup should have an "about" or "help" link, exactly for the reasons you say ("...need to know what the pros and cons of installing or refusing to install...")

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Its a new feature in 12.10 called **Web Apps**.

Here is the definition of web apps provided in Ubuntu site.

> Ubuntu Web Apps enable developers to create web applications that run
>   in web browsers, but act as if they are native applications. They
>   provide close integration to the Unity shell for functions such as
>   launch, notifications and controls.
>   [source](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/webapps/)

Comment: follow-up question: How do I make it go away? I'm not interested in a webapp popup for a large amount of the websites I visit.

Comment: @Christoph Here is the post that you're looking for: [How do I remove twitter and/or other things I “install” in FireFox](http://askubuntu.com/q/166655/62483)

Comment: @Lucio: thanks, in the meantime I had found the option in firefox where I can disable this: Edit>preferences>General> Desktop integration

Answer (score 5):

If you agreed to install the FacebookMessenger, you would see that a package named unity-webapps-facebookmessenger was installed in /usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-facebookmessenger. Other websites do the same. Search for the corresponding package in Software Center.

Webapps integrate into Unity with a launcher icon and in the messaging menu.