# How do I disable unity webapps notifications from popping up everytime I visit a supported webpage?

Tags: webapps

Every time i visit a website which supports unity webapp integration, a pop up dialog box out of the 'i' in the address bar appears which gets in my way and distracts me from what I am doing. I do not wish to click the always ignore drop down for every supported webpage, so is there a way to disable this notification box entirely (or even just uninstall webapp integration)?

Comment: You should see this !

[http://askubuntu.com/questions/249211/how-can-i-let-unity-webapps-always-run-in-chromium/553860][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/249211/how-can-i-let-unity-webapps-always-run-in-chromium/553860

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Open Firefox>Preference. In the "General" tab you see "prompt integration options for any website". Uncheck it and you're done.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't exist any more in Firefox 38. I've tried NorTicUs dconf fix to see if that will do the job.

Answer (score 3):

From this site - [How do you disable these annoying popups in firefox. Webapps](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2066329.html) - I saw you can remove WebApps integration in Firefox by going to Edit > Preferences > Desktop Integration > Untick "Prompt integration options for any website".

Or you can do it in Ubuntu preferences: "*Alternatively (and for power users!), settings can be tweaked over at dconf > com > canonical > unity > webapps.*"