# How can I globally disable Firefox's webapp prompts?

Tags: unity, 12.10, firefox, webapps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove a website from Ubuntu’s web applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166655/how-do-i-remove-a-website-from-ubuntus-web-applications)
>   [How do I disable unity webapps notifications from popping up everytime I visit a supported webpage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206710/how-do-i-disable-unity-webapps-notifications-from-popping-up-everytime-i-visit-a)

I don't use Unity so Unity-webapps (as they stand) have less than no value to me. Being prompted on various sites is actually getting annoying.

So is there a way to just disable it?