# How can I let Unity WebApps always run in Chromium?

Tags: unity, webapps

Under Ubuntu 12.10, whenever I visit a new domain in Chromium, a bar appears at the top of the window saying *Unity WebApps needs your permission to run. [Always run on this site] [Run this time]*.

I want Unity WebApps to work, but I don't want to be asked this for every single site I visit. How can I stop this notification appearing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to `chrome://plugins/` You'll find the **Unity WebApps plugin**, under it you can check "Always allowed?" so you won't see that dialog anymore. I was having the same problem and this fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed unity web player plugin

first Disable popup block if it show

If you see "**unity webplayer install now**" image in browser window then you must install it first.
Restart your browser after plugin install.

Google chrome will display a gray box with the message "Unity Player needs your permission to run". At the same time you will also see on your toolbar a message with two buttons saying "**Run this time**" and  "**Always run on this site**"Your game will run after selecting any of the message.

In this case you look on your tool-bar where you will find two buttons to activate the plugin either permanently or just for once. If you ignore this, the game will not run.

*Source* > [unity player needs your permission to run](http://unity3diy.blogspot.co.uk/2014/11/unity-player-needs-your-permission-to.html)

Comment: I just shared! Give credit to the original source :)