# Remove facebook webapp integration in Quantal

Tags: webapps, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove a website from Ubuntu’s web applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166655/how-do-i-remove-a-website-from-ubuntus-web-applications)

How can I remove the Facebook app that is displayed in Dash and in the Launcher?

When I went to Facebook using Firefox the first time, it asked me to install that. But now I can't find out how to remove it. It's not in the Ubuntu Software Centre (searched for "facebook" in installed app return no result

EDIT: here is an image:

[image]

I have tried every method mentioned but the facebook is still there. Any idea?

Comment: I added an image, please check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove all web app icons from the Dash by disabling the Firefox addons: "Unity Websites integration" (accessed from Firefox->tools-addons). You may need to restart Firefox and  log out and log back in to Ubuntu for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Note that this will remove *all* webapp integration, not just for facebook.