# How do I remove facebook from this menu?

Tags: facebook

I was on Facebook when Firefox asked me if I want to install facebook for "extra features" and I clicked "install" but now I want it gone. I can't seem to find any remove option in Software Center nor Firefox.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove a website from Ubuntu's web applications?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/166655/how-do-i-remove-a-website-from-ubuntus-web-applications)

Comment: @belacqua - Actually I tested that and it did not remove it from the menu.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado-TheWolverine  Ack. OK, still need a good answer, then.

Comment: @belacqua - Am actually very curious. Just tried MyUnity, ubuntu Tweak, dconf and did a couple of find commands. Intriguing.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado-TheWolverine  Maybe a good topic for a bounty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to remove facebook entry from the messaging menu by deleting "facebook.desktop" from

> ~/.local/share/applications

Answer (score 1):

If you have any online accounts setup this could also be what your seeing.

Check System Settings -> Online Accounts and delete your facebook account.

Comment: I never had any facebook account stored in there. I deleted everything and it just made Empathy disappear (note that Gwibber is still active).

Answer (score 1):

Best possible answer would be following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166655/how-do-i-remove-a-website-from-ubuntus-web-applications).

I followed the easier way (using Ubuntu Software Center), then I did the harder way (using dconf-editor), exited Facebook then went on it again. Now the facebook menu on the launcher no longer appears.