# Visiting launchpad.net in browser causes icon to appear in launcher, how do I remove it?

Tags: firefox, launcher, webapps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove a website from Ubuntu’s web applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166655/how-do-i-remove-a-website-from-ubuntus-web-applications)

Using Ubuntu 12.10 with Unity.

I think I agreed to install a Launchpad add-on in Firefox the first time I visited the site (launchpad.net), and ever since then, whenever I have an open tab in Firefox with any page on launchpad.net loaded, an icon appears in my Launcher desktop widget.  If I right-click on the icon and select quit, it also closes the tab in Firefox.  I've since uninstalled the Firefox add-on and rebooted, and it's still happening.

How do I make it stop? It's so annoying

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of icon in launcher]

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/166655/44179