# How to uninstall GMail webapp?

Tags: 12.10, webapps

I want to uninstall the GMail webapp, and I tried both the ways given [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166655/how-do-i-remove-a-website-from-ubuntus-web-applications/166660#16666), yet still I'm unable to.

When I searched the Software Centre for `unity-webapps-gmail`, I saw that it wasn't installed. And the "allowed-domains" in dconf-editor had no website. The Gmail icon shows up here under the Messaging Menu, and opens GMail in Firefox when clicked.

How do I unistall the Gmail web-app so that it no longer appears in the Messaging Menu?

[image: Messaging menu with Gmail entry]

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/166655/how-do-i-remove-a-website-from-ubuntus-web-applications

Answer (score 6):

You have to delete the GMail app's .desktop file from your home folder in

```
~/.local/share/applications
```

I had a lot of other garbage there, as well ...

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing in Ubuntu 14.04. Turns out, the unity webapps are stored in `/usr/share/applications` now.

If you'd like to what other webapps are installed on your system, you can navigate to the aforementioned folder:

```
cd /usr/share/applications
```

and then use the following one-liner:

```
for f in *.desktop; do if grep -q Exec=unity-webapps-runner $f; then echo $f; fi; done
```

**AT YOUR OWN RISK:** If for some reason you'd like to remove this you could replace `echo` by `rm` (and make sure you have appropriate privileges).

Answer (score 0):

Just run

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-webapps-gmail
```