# How do I remove twitter and/or other things I "install" in FireFox

Tags: firefox, uninstall, webapps

When the popup appeared saying, "Do you want to install this for quicker access" or something like that, I said Yes and clicked Yes, thus it installed.

I want to uninstall it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove a website from Ubuntu's web applications?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/166655/how-do-i-remove-a-website-from-ubuntus-web-applications)

Comment: go to the firefox addons menu !

Answer (score 0):

Start up firefox.  Either press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> or manually navigate through the toolbars (Tools>Add-ons).  This gets you to the Add-ons menu.  Now disable or remove the add-ons you don't want!

Comment: The listed extensions are not the Unity integrations that OP wants to remove.