# How to uninstall gmail app? (Ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: gmail

I was checking my gmail for the first time on Firefox in Ubuntu 12.10 and a message popped up asking something like, do I want to install the gmail app? I clicked yes and it put a letter icon into the top right of my screen, I guess what you call the tray.

Anyway it turns out this app is completely useless and I now want to remove it, but I cant! I've looked under "Installed" within the Ubuntu software centre but it isn't there.

Help!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I remove a website from Ubuntu's web applications?](http://askubuntu.com/q/166655/25656)

Answer (score 3):

Run `sudo apt-get --purge remove unity-webapps-gmail`

Comment: That uninstalled something. But the icon is still in my tray.

Comment: restart and check

Comment: And yes I have restarted.

Comment: What happen is it ok now ?

Comment: No like I said the icon is still there. I can click on it to open Gmail - but it no longer has notifications. It's like it's only half uninstalled.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/166655/25656 follow this dconf thing it will clean it up

Comment: Delete the GMail app's .desktop file from your home folder in ~/.local/share/applications.