# Beginner questions about uninstalling and more

Tags: 13.04, gnome

So I just switched from Windows to Ubuntu. I used Windows for several years, I am even comfortable wit DOS but Ubuntu gives me a headache atm. I am running 13.04 at the moment.

1. How do I uninstall stuff? I installed for example the reddit app, but I can not find it searching for it nether does sudo remove reddit work, same with google mail.
   I also installed BOINC, which was kind of a hassle to install it in the first place, and now I want to get rid of it. It installed it as a folder on the desktop but can not remove it.
2. I installed a lot of applications but if I hit "show more" the search interface does only show about 20 applications. How do I get all programs to show up?
3. A more specialized question but I tried to implement a box.com account following this tutorial http://www.maketecheasier.com/auto-mount-box-net-to-linux-desktop/2012/03/27
   but i do not have the options in the beginning, my "connect to server" looks totally different. I am able to mount it though but it says I only have 13 gb space and another 13 are full even though nothing is in there in the 50 gb account.

If necessary than I would reinstall Ubuntu, but I hope it will not be necessary.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Parotto! Ask Ubuntu is a question and answer site, and we like to keep it to one question per post. Please [edit] your question (using the `edit` link underneath the body of the post) to only include one question, and ask two other questions for the two other points.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to askubuntu. As a new user I can understand your concern, but here we follow  few rules so that you can get a good answer. First rule is don't ask many question in one topic. You are free to create as many question as you want. Second is do some search before posting the answer. Read this and help us to give a good answer next time time - https://askubuntu.com/help/asking

Here are your answers,

1. I think you want to say `uninstall` not deinstall. All your installed software are listed in `software center`. Just hit <kbd>Win</kbd> and search for software center. There you can search for the app you want to install/ uninstall. The installed one are marked with green tick.See the below image. click on the entry and you will get uninstall button. From command line you can do by `sudo apt-get remove <package_name>` (but remember package name may be different from application name)

   [image]

   The  application you installed (as I am guessing) are special web apps. You can have a look in this question too [How do I remove a website from Ubuntu's web applications?](https://askubuntu.com/q/166655/35775)
2. **regarding list of installed app**, again you can open software center and see *Installed* tab. See above screen shot

   or you can hit <kbd>win</kbd>, keep pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> (or click on the application scope in below) and see details. See the screenshot below. You can just type on the name to search any application after pressing win

   [image]
3. And **connecting to a wedav** account, I recommend another application. Nautilus has changed since that tutorial was written. This answer goes as a task for you, you can easily install an application named `Gigolo`. So to do so, as I told, search and open software center, search for `Gigolo` and install it. From there it is pretty easy.

Enjoy ubuntu and comeback if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will be obey the rules :) Was just late yesterday.