# How to remove Launchpad app/webapp?

Tags: unity-dash, launchpad, webapps

I was browsing Launchpad and it asked to install a helper app.  I thought that this was the Firefox extension so I said yes.  Now I have this launcher app that will open a Firefox window directly to Launchpad from my unity dash.

I want to remove it and I can't.  I removed the Firefox extension and it's still there.  I removed the Unity webapps Firefox extension and it's still there.  I tried to purge "launchpad" and my system says that it doesn't exist.  I searched Launchpad for information on this app but found nothing I could understand that seemed to be relevant.  But it's still there, staring at me from the Unity dash.

Can anyone help me get this thing out of my system? Running Ubuntu 13.10

I tried this question but it didn't work:

- [How do I remove a website from Ubuntu's web applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166655/how-do-i-remove-a-website-from-ubuntus-web-applications)

"Package 'unity-webapps-launchpad' is not installed, so not removed" and the Launchpad Firefox Launcher icon is STILL in the dash. Any other ideas?

Comment: The package name is `unity-webapps-launchpad`. Try to remove it through the terminal (CTRL+ALT+T). Run `sudo apt-get remove unity-webapps-launchpad`

Comment: @NikTh why not add that as answers?

Comment: @Braiam I think it's too short for an answer, but the main reason is, that I was almost sure that this question it's a duplicate. I didn't search before(when I added the comment) but I searched now and I found it. ;-)

Comment: Sorry guys this is NOT a duplicate.  I had already done that step but I did it again anyway.  When I did as suggested I got this response: "Package 'unity-webapps-launchpad' is not installed, so not removed" and the Launchpad Firefox Launcher icon is STILL in the dash.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks for NOT reading my comment and and leaving me with my problem. The answers you suggested did NOT work hence this is a different issue and NOT a duplicate.  But hey what do I know.

Comment: I figured it out and it **DEFINITELY was NOT a duplicate!**  The answer is that it was `unity-webapps-runner -n 'TGF1bmNocGFkAA==' -d 'launchpad.net' %u`.  I found it and deleted it with Alacart.  Now it's gone from my dash.