# What is an "integration script" and why would I want one?

Tags: firefox, webapps

When I navigate to Launchpad in Firefox, a pop-up appears:

[image: integration script available unity-webapps-launchpad]

I think, despite its failure to form a coherent question, it's trying to ask me if I want to install an "integration script" called "unity-webapps-launchpad".

Sadly, it does not provide me with enough information to make an informed decision, nor does it refer me to a source where I can learn more about it.
 The top result in my web searches on the topic is my own [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1058801). While this cyclical phenomenon provides a brief source of amusement, it is ultimately unhelpful. So, once again, I've come to Ask Ubuntu for a nudge in the right direction.

What is this thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An integration script is a [JavaScript browser extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript) that facilitates integration of a specific [web application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application) with Unity via the [WebApps feature introduced in Ubuntu 12.10](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/unity-webapps-available-in-ubuntu-1210.html).

This prompt is generated by the [Unity Desktop Integration](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/xul-ext-unity) browser extension when [a package providing an integration script](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=unity-webapps-&searchon=names&suite=quantal&section=all) is available in Ubuntu's repositories but is not installed. The prompt's wording [will likely be improved](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-firefox-extension/+bug/1058816) in the future.

See also:

- [How do I use Ubuntu's web application integration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165662/how-do-i-use-ubuntus-web-application-integration)
- [How do I remove a website from Ubuntu's web applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166655/how-do-i-remove-a-website-from-ubuntus-web-applications)