# Is there a way to request support for web applications not currently supported?

Tags: 12.10, webapps

I'm enjoying 12.10's webapp integration, and I'm curious how new web applications will be added to the list of supported sites. (A list can be found in the answer to [How do I use Ubuntu's web application integration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165662/how-do-i-use-ubuntus-web-application-integration))

I'd love to see StackExchange, GitHub, and especially and Microsoft Outlook Web App added to that list. Is there a way that requests can be made?

Comment: If you're feeling adventurous you can [read the documentation](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/webapps/) and create one or more yourself.

Comment: Request to whom? Unity developers already provided an API to build web apps. You can build your own webapp using it:)

Comment: @Tachyons Ah. I wasn't sure who was building these apps, thought that Canonical was behind it.

Comment: ^Pre installed web apps are developed by canonical, additional  web app integration can be done by users

Comment: For Outlook Web App, you can see this Greasemonkey script that I managed to create: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/163214

Comment: @Pisu When I clicked the 'install' button I got a 404

Comment: Please try now, I removed the require needing. Remember to edit the script change "exchange-server" to your server name