# howto use Webb Apps feature

Tags: webapps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use Ubuntu’s web application integration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165662/how-do-i-use-ubuntus-web-application-integration)

Ok, I've just decided to try Ubuntu distro. Burned a bootable USB and started playing. After watching "top 10 features" video I've though webapps feature is awesome - if I could make it work I could get some damn cool results in my workshop (getting Gmail, FB, Twitter tabs or even hopefully Basecamp would speed my work up).
Sadly I can't access this feature. On the video I can see a sort of prompt near address bar that apears when the guy enters twitter.
On my computer I got nothing. Any idea howto make it work?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the Web Apps feature is currently broken. I was excited to use it as well, but after some research it seems like we're just going to have to wait it out until a fix is made.