# Software center shows that Google Docs has been installed

Tags: security

I made a Gmail to message the owners of a blog I follow because some of their recent posts seemed like personal attacks. After I messaged them I have no reply and they deleted my disqus post on their site. I just noticed Google docs had been installed on my machine. I looked it up in the history section of software center and it says it was installed at 5:25 p. m. On Tuesday. Anything I can do to catch these hackers?

Comment: Your machine almost certainly wasn't hacked. Out of the box, there's no way a user across the net can do anything on your machine. Even if your machine was hacked, even though it is incredibly unlikely, installing google docs is comically bad hacking.

Comment: I was fiddling with net settings earlier. Following some of the instructions on this site. http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1204-lts-server-part-1-basics

Comment: @msw I disagree. Browser hacking is an issue. I don't see why there could not be any hidden vulnerabilities in linux. I would switch of the internet, look at the logs, mail google and see what activity has been logged for that period of time, mail disqus, etc. If you have personal info to protect, you should be careful (but not crazy).

Comment: That said, I am not sure whether this really is a hack. It seems more like you inadvertedly installed something.

Comment: May you show us these docs so we can take a look if there is some suspicious code?

Answer (score 2):

It seems far more likely that you clicked Okay when you were prompted to allow Ubuntu to [integrate Google Apps as a web-app](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165662/how-do-i-use-ubuntus-web-application-integration). Ubuntu will do that.

I suggest that the problem here is heightened paranoia. That's not always a bad thing but you're seeing shadows where there are likely non. I'd suggest some herbal tea.