# Cannot find my PWA in Ubuntu

Tags: chromium, youtube, webapps, desktop-apps

I have installed in Ubuntu -> Outlook and Youtube using Progressive Web Apps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3oCyfcHSeDc

However, I cannot find my new PWAs between my old apps, I restarted Ubuntu but unfortunately is not shown in "Show Applications"

In other distros PWA are added automatically: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0wi7yecUdc

Probably I'm missing something, any help would be really appreciated!

**Update**: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.

Comment: Thank you David, I updated with the Ubuntu version!

Comment: Is this any useful? https://askubuntu.com/questions/31427/how-do-i-put-a-web-application-on-the-launcher Or this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/165662/how-do-i-use-ubuntus-web-application-integration

Comment: Thank you Levente, but that's for Web Apps no PWA, check this Linux Desktop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0wi7yecUdc with PWA I just need to click in install on the browser

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work in Ubuntu 22.10, with some caveats. I have tried the following, for the [Microsoft Teams PWA](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams-blog/microsoft-teams-progressive-web-app-now-available-on-linux/ba-p/3669846):

- Installing from Chromium, where Chromium is installed as a snap package. **This does not work.** The PWA launches, but Ubuntu just sees it as a second Chromium window. It is grouped under Chromium in the Dash, and Teams is not added to the app drawer, so there is no way to start it after closing it (except going through Chromium again, which kind of defeats the purpose).
- Installing from Chrome, where Chrome is installed as an apt package (`google-chrome-stable`). **This works :).** After clicking install from Chrome, Ubuntu initially treats it as a second Chrome window. However, I closed the window, checked the app drawer, and there it was, with the Teams icon and everything. I started the application and this time, Ubuntu correctly considered it a separate application that I could pin to my Dash.

I did not try installing a Chromium apt package, so I don't know whether snap was the reason it didn't work with my Chromium installation. I suspect it is. I did not try with Firefox either, because unfortunately, Teams does not fully support Firefox.

Some screenshots showing the end result:

The app Drawer:

[image: app drawer]

The Dash (left) and PWA (right):

[image: dash]
[image: PWA]

The error in the screenshot is due to the uMatrix browser extension (yes, your browser extensions run in the the PWA as well) blocking some things.

The PWA is added under a *Chrome Apps* menu in your applications, as shown in the screenshot below. (If you're using the default Ubuntu desktop, you won't notice, as the app drawer doesn't show menus, only their contents).
[image]

Comment: Nice. It is though a pity `google-chrome-stable` is not available as an APT package by default.

Comment: Installing Chromium from a apt package does not work either. Installing Chrome from apt package works just fine, as you described. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Open chrome, click the Apps icon below the url bar. your installed PWA app should be there.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1179324)

Comment: Having to open a browser to launch a PWA is not how PWAs are supposed to work. They should be startable like any native app, usually from a desktop icon.