# How do I pin a website shortcut to the Launcher?

Tags: firefox, launcher, shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I put a web application on the Launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31427/how-do-i-put-a-web-application-on-the-launcher)

I'm using Firefox. I created a shortcut to a much-used website on my desktop, but when I drag the shortcut icon to the Launcher it won't stick.