# How to install trello in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, software-installation

is there any command to install Trello in ubuntu? I search on their
 website but there is no official application for ubuntu-desktop.

Comment: What is trello?

Comment: Trello is a task management app

Comment: Why not ask the developers if their app can be installed on Ubuntu?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, it's very far from an official client and is a different take on the whole design, still might come useful (if everything goes well, expect an unlimited trial) - https://snapcraft.io/focus-project

Still bogus, and lots of things aren't supported, but I mostly like using it :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it can be done. As it is not available officially, you have to download it from this git repository [link to repo](https://github.com/danielchatfield/trello-desktop/releases/tag/v0.1.9). Use the command below to download the software :

```
wget https://github.com/danielchatfield/trello-desktop/releases/download/v0.1.9/Trello-linux-0.1.9.zip -O trello.zip
```

Use the following commands to install the downloaded file :

```
sudo mkdir /opt/trello

sudo unzip trello.zip -d /opt/trello/
```

You can now use `trello`, type `trello` in the terminal to launch it, or you can create a desktop shortcut as given below.

---

Create a shortcut to facilitate program execution :

```
sudo ln -sf /opt/trello/Trello /usr/bin/trello
```

Create a launcher for the program by running the command below :

```
echo -e '[Desktop Entry]\n Version=1.0\n Name=trello\n Exec=/opt/trello/Trello\n Icon=/opt/trello/resources/app/static/Icon.png\n Type=Application\n Categories=Application' | sudo tee /usr/share/applications/trello.desktop
```

Put the shortcut on your desktop using the system file manager or the command below, and use it to start the program :

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/share/applications/trello.desktop
```

After this make sure that you have libgconf2-4 installed in your system. If you don't have, then install it using this command :

```
sudo apt-get install libgconf2-4
```

Comment: can we start it using `trello` command?

Comment: yes you can start the application using the command  `trello`

Comment: I'm on Pop!_OS 20.04 (technically Ubuntu 20.04) and I couldn't download libgconf2-4, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

As of today, Trello does not have a native Linux app.
In my opinion, there are 2 meaningful things you can do about this:

- Use the unofficial app mentioned in the answer by [matinict](https://askubuntu.com/users/785827/matinict).
- Or use a **site specific browser window with Trello app quickly callable by a keyboard shortcut**. I use this as an alternative to Ubuntu Todo app which is unfortunately not syncing with the cloud.

**Here is how to do it with Firefox** v73+:

1. go to `about:config`, `Accept the Risk and Continue`
2. search for `ssb` and using double-click flip it to true
3. restart Firefox (I know about ssb thanks to [this post of Andrew Braun](https://www.maketecheasier.com/enable-site-specific-browser-firefox/))
4. now the command `firefox --ssb https://trello.com/yourboard` should work
5. now go to `Ubuntu Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts > Add`
6. fill in the command, specify a shortcut (I use `Super + F1`) and there you go, you have a **Trello window quickly callable by a keyboard shortcut.**

**Here is how to do it with Chromium** (I guess the same-ish applies for Chrome):

1. `sudo apt install chromium-browser`
2. open your Trello board in the Chromium browser
3. click the `3 dots icon` in the top right corner and choose `More tools > Create Shortcut`
4. give the shortcut a name and check `Open as window`
5. go to your Desktop where you will find a file named `chrome-somethingsomething.Desktop`
6. open it with a text editor and copy the `app-id`
7. this command opens the shortcut: `/snap/bin/chromium --app-id=<the app id you have copied>`
8. do the steps 5. and 6. from the Firefox list.

**Desktop shortcut instead of keyboard shortcut:**

If you are more interested in "clicking an icon", [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31427/how-do-i-put-a-web-application-on-the-launcher) might be useful to you but I do not use it.

Other remarks:

- chromium will remember the window position, which is cool
- you can obviously close the window quickly with Alt+F4
- of course, you can delete the .Desktop file from the Desktop
- you can use Trello smartphone app so you have your todos always at hand

Answer (score 1):

By adding this PPA to your system, You can update your system with unsupported packages from this untrusted PPA by adding `ppa:atareao/trello-desktop` to your system's Software Sources.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/trello-desktop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install trello-desktop
```

or

```
sudo snap install so-trello
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply install Whale : https://www.electronjs.org/apps/whale

It's an unofficial Trello app that works flawlessly (I'm using Ubuntu Studio 20.04).

Comment: How come I didn't know about this one! I'll give it a try.

Additionally there's a snapped electron app (turned up during the summer) worth mentioning (just came here to do that :) but then a comment might do well).

Might be a 'fork' of what matinct mentioned above via a ppa.

https://snapcraft.io/trello-desktop

Answer (score 0):

**Focus|Project** is for now a PC app, a [Trello integration](https://trello.com/integrations/#/focus%7CProject), which **practically can be used as a speedy although reduced functionality Trello client** (with some extras too!)

I'd put it as **a todo ticker/note taker** (incl. annotated images as attachments combined with a live markdown preview, but also desktop notifications) for now, with a growing set of features for offline Trello use (for starters it now supports a read-only board history for on/offline use in the form of fast to access, searchable [data snapshots](https://f-p.app/snapshots.html)).

**It's still in beta**, but in my experience it works out well on at least Ubuntu as a lightweight short-range PM aide for the web (or electron) based heavier artillery.

You should be able to simply install it from Ubuntu Software under the `focus-project` name, or via the console:

```
snap install focus-project
```

At the moment it works off either a developer token (albeit that may or may not be a stretch for some - if it's prohibitive, let me know!) or a password-restricted, but more proper authorization for beta testers on Linux (ask :) ).

Enjoy!

(Disclaimer: I am the author)

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow this link for easy installation process
https://snapcraft.io/install/trello-desktop/ubuntu#install